# Quoting and escaping

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

While reading the GNU Make manual, I have faced with the term "quoting". What does it mean in programming, how it differs from escaping? I am trying to understend the general concept. Below is a fragment of GNU Make manual:

> ‘%’ characters in a vpath directive’s pattern can be quoted with preceding backslashes (‘\’). Backslashes that would otherwise quote ‘%’ characters can be quoted with more backslashes. Backslashes that quote ‘%’ characters or other backslashes are removed from the pattern before it is compared to file names. Backslashes that are not in danger of quoting ‘%’ characters go unmolested.

Sometimes documentations is refering to the escaping, sometimes to quoting, I am little confused.

Comment: Here they mean the same thing.  They can usually be used interchangeably.  More generally, "escaping" is usually used to mean that any special meaning of the next character is ignored, while "quoting" usually refers to putting delimiters around a longer string such that any special meaning of any character in that quoted string is ignored.  In that way, the above manual excerpt might better use "escape", but they mean the same thing.

Comment: @MadScientist Indeed "escape" would be better because quoting is sometimes more complex than just ignoring the special meaning of all characters in the quoted string. Double quotes, for instance, are used to prevent word splitting by shells but they do not ignore the special meaning of all characters (e.g. `$`).

Comment: True, but in that sense "quoting" is ambiguous and you'd need to clarify it as "single quote" or "double quote" because they have different behaviors.